# How long do ISPs retain data?

Tags: privacy, isp

I recently came across an article informing people about how long major ISP’s store user data such as IP assignments and other user data. On average, companies supposedly stored this data for 6 months (180 days). Is this true? and wouldn’t this cause problems with the people who deem this as a safety concern considering 6 months is a short amount of time? I know that retaining data is pricey, but still?

Comment: It would be really difficult to determine what the average policy was.  I would think that anyone who would go to the trouble to make such a determination would probably want to publish the data in some manner to try to recoup some of the expense of gathering that data. That said, I would guess that by this they mean they keep the log files that record when a particular user connected and what IP address they were given. Depending on the organization in question, they may have a requirement to keep the data for a given length of time. Finding those requirements might be easier.

Comment: I'm not sure that anyone can speak for all the ISPs in the world. And I'm not sure that you have defined what problems would be caused, so I'm not sure how to answer that part of your question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the range of possible answers is too broad, and depends on jurisdiction.

Answer (score 1):

Data retention is limited by country law (and GDPR in EU).

In my country, the law says 6 months so it's 6 months., but it may differ depending on your location and implicit legislation.